# AudioInputStream.close() não funcionando (Unable to delete file)

Tags: java, windows, inputstream

Estou tendo um problema com um AudioInputStream.

Após fazer os ajustes que eu preciso, eu dou um `AudioInputStream.close()` (equivalente ao `InputStream.close()`) para eu poder deletar o arquivo posteriormente.

Porém ao fazer isso a seguinte exception é apresentada:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\tmp\documentos\3542\1455814425556.wav
```

E se eu caminho até o diretório do arquivo e tento deletar manualmente o windows avisa que ele esta sendo usado por outro processo (java.exe).

Pesquisando, eu verifiquei que esse bug foi reportado no jira do openjdk (**que não é o que eu uso atualmente**): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8013586 porém não consegui compreender se uma solução foi encontrada.

Mais alguns detalhes que possam ser úteis:

```
Versão do Java: 1.8.0_60
Versão do JDK: 1.7.0_79
SO: Windows 10
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como isso possa ser resolvido?